# How to pipe a character set on hydra

Tags: linux, hashcat, hydra, wordlist

How to pipe a characterset to Hydra.

Something like this which can be done on hashcat

```
(crunch 8 8 123456789| hashcat -m 0 ce5cff0195a6b059a32411b6202ab49)
```

Comment: Do not repost closed questions.

Comment: That duplicate was found by googling "pipe to hydra" (the 2nd hit)